# Unlock iPhone and accessibility

Tags: iphone, accessibility

I need my app disable the unlock functionnality, I know it's not allowed by Apple. My app must be accessible for old or handicap person, in this case, do you think that Apple can allow my app?

Answer (score 1):

Apple will not allow this. If your app is used by people with disabilities severe enough that they can't unlock an iPhone then your developing on the wrong platform. If someone can't unlock an iPhone how will they use all it's other features including your app? It's possible to set the iPhone to never autolock but this is something the user has to do in settings and your app can not do it. You could pop up a dialog though the first time your app is launched explaining how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to work on a function like this, because the Unlock-Screen is a part of the *Springboard.app*. You can't change something in another app, **this is not possible.**
You  would need to jailbreak the phones for changing something in the Springboard.app.

Answer (score 0):

No, no matter what your reason might be, Apple won't allow such an App because of various reasons (it could break any time due to API changes etc)